# PHP: what could cause FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW to return FALSE?

Tags: php, filter-var, sanitization

After returning to a script from a long absence, I'm am stuck on a suddenly failing sanitization.
I found the problem in a filter unexpectedly returning `false`.

Here's an example to replicate my unintended results:

```
$test = [ 'apple', 'bananna', 'orange', 'lime', 'grape', ];
var_export( filter_var( $test, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW ));  // false
```

I thought that `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` is supposed to just return the input (an array in this case) unchanged.
Am I wrong in my understanding/approach?

**NOTE:**
My code has to be strictly self-reliant and as light-weight as possible, so rather than loading 3rd party libraries/classes, I'm just writing-in simple helper functions where needed.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$filters = [
    'sanitize' => [ 
        'foo' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
        'bar' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,
    ],
    'validate' => [
        'foo' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
        'bar' => [
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
            'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
            'options' => [ 'regexp' => '/(apple|grape)/' ],
        ],
    ],
];

$test = [
    'malicious' => 'something bad',
    'foo' => 'test@ema.il',
    'bar' => [ 'apple', 'grape', 'orange', ],
];

// validate
$checked = sanitizeInput( $filters, $test );

// sanitizer
function sanitizeInput( $f, $input )
{
    // sanitize
    $sanitized  = filter_var_array( $input, $f['sanitize'] )

    // validate
    $validated  = filter_var_array( $sanitized, $f['validate'] );

    // if anything appears to have failed validation (was set to FALSE)
    if( FALSE !== strpos( json_encode($validated), 'false' ))
    {
        ...
```

As you can see, this approach requires that `bar` passes sanitization, even though no sanitizing action is necessary.

Am I misunderstanding `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Filter Flags is Missing

It looks like you have not added the proper flags for the sanitize part of the `filter_var_array`

Whenever you are processing an array, you have to include the flag `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY`

Hence without the flag, you were getting the response as `false`

**Note:** `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` just optionally strips or encodes special characters. Also this is the default filter.

**Example**

```
$test['bar'] = array( 'apple', 'bananna', 'orange', 'lime', 'grape' );

$san['bar'] = [
  'filter' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,
  'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
];

print_r(filter_var_array( $test, $san ));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => bananna
            [2] => orange
            [3] => lime
            [4] => grape
        )

)
```

**Edited Working Code**

```
$filters = [
    'sanitize' => [ 
        'foo' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
        'bar' =>  [
            'filter' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,
            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
        ],
    ],
    'validate' => [
        'foo' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
        'bar' => [
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
            'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
            'options' => [ 'regexp' => '/(apple|grape)/' ],
        ],
    ],
];

$test = [
    'malicious' => 'something bad',
    'foo' => 'test@ema.il',
    'bar' => [ 'apple', 'grape', 'orange', ],
];

// validate
$checked = sanitizeInput( $filters, $test );

// sanitizer
function sanitizeInput( $f, $input ) {
  
    // sanitize
    $sanitized  = filter_var_array( $input, $f['sanitize'] );

print_r($sanitized);

    // validate
    $validated  = filter_var_array( $sanitized, $f['validate'] );

    // if anything appears to have failed validation (was set to FALSE)
    if( FALSE !== strpos( json_encode($validated), 'false' )) {}

    return $validated;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns false since `filter_var()` can't validate array. And `filter_var_array()` is like running `filter_var()` to each subject array's value. You can try to use array as `bar`'s value inside `sanitize` array, with `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` as filter and `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` as flags

```
'sanitize' => [ 
    'foo' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
    'bar' =>  [
            'filter' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,
            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
            ],
],
```

Another thing to note is since you only use `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` without specifying flags, it will just do nothing. So not sanitizing it is the same. Though it won't work on your case because it will not be passed to validation.